# on Google App Engine 500 Error, it should be 200 instead of 500

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

```
requestToken = function() {
    var getTokenURI = '/gettoken?userid=' + userid;
    var httpRequest = makeRequest(getTokenURI, true);

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
                openChannel(httpRequest.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('ERROR: AJAX request status = ' + httpRequest.status);
            }
        }
    }
};

function makeRequest(url, async) {
    var httpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // IE
        try {

            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        } catch (e) {
            try {

                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {

        return false;
    }

    httpRequest.open('POST', url, async);
    httpRequest.send();

    return httpRequest;
}
```

it is running excellent on localhost...but on google app engine it httpRequest.status equals 500 and goes in else statement.
WHY?

LOG on google app engine:

```
/getFriendList?userid=d 500 253ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
175.110.179.86 - - [17/Dec/2012:08:35:33 -0800] "POST /getFriendList?userid=d HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://faisalimmsngr.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11" "faisalimmsngr.appspot.com" ms=254 cpu_ms=110 instance=00c61b117caf2d11ca57d2a2296ccd0b902b038a
W 2012-12-17 08:35:33.272
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@10ff62a{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~faisalimmsngr/1.363934467542140431}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/FriendServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/MessageServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/TokenServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/FriendServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-c04431eac3a1f275(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: How should we know? What does it say in the App Engine logs?

Comment: Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1353154{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~faisalimmsngr/1.363934024060099292}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/FriendServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/MessageServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/TokenServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]

Comment: show us the makeRequest method.

Comment: 500 just means that the server threw an exception. Just concentrate on fixing that exception and continue. This problem has at least got completely nothing to do with JS/Ajax. The exception in question is at least extremely self-explaining (and Googlable) `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: adv/web/mid/exam/FriendServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`. Just recompile that class (and most likely also all the other code) with the right Java version supported by GAE.

Comment: Please paste your code in the question as an edit instead of vomiting it in comments...

Comment: but it works fine on localhost:8080

Comment: Of course it would work fine when you run Java 1.7 yourself at localhost. GAE in production doesn't run Java 1.7. As commented before, you just need to recompile that class (and most likely also all the other code) with the right Java version supported by GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you use JDK 7. You should use JDK 6.